# How do you log into an account in Active Directory that doesn't have a password set?

Tags: active-directory, ldap

I'm doing some InfoSec testing and I've discovered some accounts that don't have a password set.

I'm wondering if there is a way to can log into these accounts. I know that for these accounts, their password will be required to be reset upon login, but I'm not sure how to log in. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It might help if you tell us how you determined that they don't have a password set. But if that truly is the case, then there are only two possibilities:

1. The accounts are disabled. This might happen if the accounts are created via automation. Creating accounts has to be done in two steps: create the account (which is created disabled), then set the password and enable it. You can't enable it without setting a password.
2. The accounts have the `ADS_UF_PASSWD_NOTREQD` flag set in the [`userAccountControl`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adschema/a-useraccountcontrol) attribute. This means the account can be enabled with no password and you can login with such an account by just not putting anything as the password. You can read more about this [here](https://itfordummies.net/2017/08/28/active-directory-password-not-required/) if you'd like.